# How to make Thread Pool Tasks in abstract function type?

Tags: c++, task, threadpool, abstraction

I'm trying to implement very simple C++ Thread Pool.
So far, I've checked it working.
However, I want to make tasks in abstract form.
I've searched for dozens of articles, they don't seem what I want.
(Perhaps my keyword wasn't appropriate...)
Currently, only

```
void (*)()
```

form can be accepted as task function.
Simple code is written below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <Windows.h>

class CYSThreadPool
{
private:

    static std::thread** s_ppThreads;
    static long s_lThreadCount;
    static bool s_bJoin;
    static std::mutex* s_pMutexJoin;

    static std::queue<void (*)()> s_queueTasks;
    static std::mutex* s_pMutexTasks;

    CYSThreadPool(){}
    ~CYSThreadPool(){}

    static void ThreadFunction()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (!s_pMutexJoin->try_lock())
                continue;

            bool bJoin = s_bJoin;
            s_pMutexJoin->unlock();

            if (bJoin)
                break;

            if (!s_pMutexTasks->try_lock())
                continue;

            void (*fp)() = nullptr;
            if (s_queueTasks.size() > 0ull)
            {
                fp = s_queueTasks.front();
                s_queueTasks.pop();
            }

            s_pMutexTasks->unlock();

            if (fp != nullptr)
                fp();
        }
    }

public:

    enum class EResult : unsigned long
    {
        Success = 0ul,
        Fail_Undefined = 1ul,
        Fail_InvalidThreadCount = 2ul,
        Fail_ArgumentNull = 3ul
    };

    static const EResult Join()
    {
        if (s_ppThreads == nullptr)
        {
            if (s_lThreadCount == 0l)
                return EResult::Success;
            else
                return EResult::Fail_Undefined;
        }
        else
        {
            if (s_lThreadCount <= 0l)
                return EResult::Fail_Undefined;
            else
            {
                s_pMutexJoin->lock();
                s_bJoin = true;
                s_pMutexJoin->unlock();

                for (long i = 0l; i < s_lThreadCount; ++i)
                {
                    s_ppThreads[i]->join();
                    s_ppThreads[i] = nullptr;
                }

                delete s_ppThreads;
                s_ppThreads = nullptr;
                s_lThreadCount = 0l;

                s_pMutexJoin->lock();
                s_bJoin = false;
                s_pMutexJoin->unlock();
            }
        }

        return EResult::Success;
    }

    static const EResult CreateThreads(const long _lThreadCount)
    {
        if (_lThreadCount < 0l)
            return EResult::Fail_InvalidThreadCount;

        if (Join() != EResult::Success)
            return EResult::Fail_Undefined;

        if (_lThreadCount == 0l)
            return EResult::Success;

        s_ppThreads = new std::thread*[_lThreadCount]{};

        for (long i = 0l; i < _lThreadCount; ++i)
            s_ppThreads[i] = new std::thread(ThreadFunction);

        s_lThreadCount = _lThreadCount;

        return EResult::Success;
    }

    static const EResult AddTask(void (*_fp)())
    {
        if (_fp == nullptr)
            return EResult::Fail_ArgumentNull;

        s_pMutexTasks->lock();
        s_queueTasks.push(_fp);
        s_pMutexTasks->unlock();

        return EResult::Success;
    }
};

std::thread** CYSThreadPool::s_ppThreads = nullptr;
long CYSThreadPool::s_lThreadCount = 0l;
bool CYSThreadPool::s_bJoin = false;
std::mutex* CYSThreadPool::s_pMutexJoin = new std::mutex();
std::queue<void (*)()> CYSThreadPool::s_queueTasks;
std::mutex* CYSThreadPool::s_pMutexTasks = new std::mutex();

void Test0()
{
    for (long i = 0l; i < 100000l; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "A";
    }
}

int main()
{
    CYSThreadPool::EResult eResult = CYSThreadPool::Join();
    eResult = CYSThreadPool::CreateThreads(-1l);
    eResult = CYSThreadPool::CreateThreads(1l);
    eResult = CYSThreadPool::CreateThreads(0l);
    eResult = CYSThreadPool::CreateThreads(2l);

    CYSThreadPool::AddTask(Test0);

    Sleep(1000ul);

    CYSThreadPool::Join();

    return 0;
}
```

Kind and elaborated answer will be truly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

What I meant by 'Function in abstract form' is to get any function types other than void (*)().
Such as void (*)(long), void (*)(ID3D12Resource1*, IDXGISwapChain), or HResult (*)(ID3D12Device6*, ID3D12Resource1*, IDXGISwapChain) and so on.

Thanks for the comment about using condition_variable instead of try_lock and wrapping fp() into try-catch. I'm sorry but I don't think I'm catching what you mean. May I ask for more detail?

Comment: What is an _"abstract form"_? Can you add an example of what tasks this thread pool should be able to handle?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, freakish and Timo!

Comment: use concurrencpp: https://github.com/David-Haim/concurrencpp `auto runtime = concurrencpp::make_runtime();  runtime->thread_pool_executor()->enqueue(...);`. don't write your own threadpool.

Answer (score 2):

So here are few things to improve your code:

1. You can use [std::function<void()>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) instead of `void(*)()`. This will allow you to call any callable, not only function pointers, by wrapping them in a lambda, e.g. `CYSThreadPool::AddTask([]() { Add(3, 1); });`.
2. Even better, make an abstract base class, say `Task` with virtual `.Run()` method and use it instead. You can derive `FunctionPointerTask` or `StdFunctionTask` (you can change names obviously) out of it if you want. You can create say `ProcessResource1Task` and pass necessary arguments to constructor so that `.Run()` only executes it.
3. Your `ThreadFunction` workers are very inefficient. You spin all the time on `try_lock`. Don't. Use [condition_variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) instead.
4. Even better, move the queueing stuff into a separate thread-safe queue class.
5. Your code is not exception-safe. Don't use manual lock/try_lock, use [lock_guard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) or [unique_lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) instead. As it is your code can easily deadlock. If you must use manual lock/try_lock then you have to use try-catch.
6. Lots of static variables. Don't. Make all of them non-static members, add appropriate constructors and destructor. Your thread pool, once joined is completely unusable. Plus Join() is not thread-safe (it would matter less if the thread pool wasn't completely static).
7. You can improve performance by making `bool s_bJoin` [atomic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic). It's not necessary to read/write it under the lock.

There might be some other issues, that's what I can see for now.

You can also view [this code](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool/blob/master/ThreadPool.h) for a not bad thread pool implementation. It is short and utilizes most of the above hints.

Comment: Wow, quite a lot of things to fix! Thank you for elaboration! It seems it will take a day or two for me to search and understand what you've pointed. This is really helping!